# Assign values to a variable of a class and use that value to assign to another variable from another class

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble assigning the value of a variable from one class to another class. I have tried to do it in several ways but none works, the variable still has no value inside my method.

First Class:

```
namespace Simulador
{
    public partial class Cidade : Window
    {
        private int QNTTodinho;

        private void todinhobotao_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TodinhoBotaoo();
        }

        public void TodinhoBotaoo()
        {
             QNTTodinho += 1;
             MainWindow Valor = new MainWindow(QNTTodinho);
        }
    }
}
```

Second Class:

```
namespace Simulador
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private int QNTTodinho;

        public MainWindow(int qNTTodinho)
        {
            QNTTodinho = Convert.ToInt32(qNTTodinho);
        }

        private void Salgadinho_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dinheiro22.Content = QNTTodinho.ToString();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Where did you declare   QNTTodinho in your MainWindow? does it compile?

Comment: Which value doesn't update? There are few strange elements in your code like 'MainWindow Valor' which local. Also where is the definition of `QNTTodinho` in 'MainWindow`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to transcribe

Comment: Now it's right.

Comment: Why are you converting an `int` to an `int` with `Convert.ToInt32`?

Comment: Please show the several ways that you've tried. Also let us know what you're trying to achieve. You really should read [ask].

Comment: I was trying everything, but thank you very much for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that the startup form for your application is 
`MainWindow`. Which means you are creating an instance of `MainWindow` and running it as the main application window.

If this is the case, then creating another instance of `MainWindow` like what you are doing and passing the integer to it in the constructor wouldn't affect the actual main window. It is just setting the value in a copy of the `MainWindow` and directly scrapping that copy afterwards.

One way to fix that, although not the best practice, is to change the member you want to modify to be a static member, like that:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static int QntTodinho { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
    }

    private void Salgadinho_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dinheiro22.Content = this.QntTodinho.ToString();
    }
 }

public partial class Cidade : Window
{
    private int qntTodinho = 0;

    private void todinhobotao_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TodinhoBotaoo();
    }

    public void TodinhoBotaoo()
    {
         this.qntTodinho += 1;
         MainWindow.QntTodinho = this.qntTodinho;
    }
}
```

Notice as well that I've done the following changes:

- Used pascalCasing for private member
- Used CamelCasing for public member
- Get rid of Convert.ToInt32 as it is not needed

Things to consider with this solution are mainly thread safety and the lack of ways to notify `MainWindow` when the value changes.